# How to activate 'Hold ON' in plotting in R with different axes size?

Tags: r, plot

I want to have two different plots in one figure in R. I do the following coding:

```
x1 <- runif(190, 5.0, 7.5)
y1 <- runif(190, 6.0, 9.5)
# another set of numbers
x2 <- runif(200, 9, 11)
y2 <- runif(200, 9.0, 13.5)
# one more set
x3 <- c(16,16.2)
y3 <- c(21.5, 21.7)
# fourth set
x4 <- c(6,7.5, 8.5, 11, 12, 5, 5.5)
y4 <- c(11,13,13.5, 5, 14, 11, 4 )
#take all except x3, y3
x = c(x1,x2,  x4)
y = c(y1,y2,  y4)
# dataset
dt = data.frame(x,y)
#cluster into two
kr <- kmeans(dt, 2)
#plot
plot(dt[c("x", "y")], col = kr$cluster, ylim = range(c(3.5, 22)), frame= FALSE)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x3,y3, col='blue', ylim = range(c(3.5, 22)))
```

but the result is like this image: [image]

In Matlab there is Hold On feature, which fits plots automatically.
Any suggestion in R please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add points to a plot in R you can do:

```
plot(dt[c("x", "y")], col = kr$cluster, ylim = range(c(3.5, 22)), frame= FALSE)

points(x3,y3, col='blue')
```

You can also add lines with `lines`

You just need to adjust `xlim` and `ylim` in the first plot to be sure all the data you add fit, there won't be any automatic resizing.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpreting the question, but it appears that you're after a method of displaying the plots on a grid?

You can used `par(mfrow = c(nrow, ncol))` before the first plot call.

So for your example you can use the following to display two plots side-by-side:

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(dt[c("x", "y")], col = kr$cluster, ylim = range(c(3.5, 22)), frame= FALSE)
plot(x3,y3, col='blue', ylim = range(c(3.5, 22)))
```

[image: You can see the result here]

Comment: Thanks but I want them in the same figure.